# How to stop forever from retrying?

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, npm, forever

I have a nodejs server. I use forever to start the server using the following batch script:

```
c:\

cd c:\somefolder

forever start server.js

sleep 10

pause
```

The issue is if the server fails to start it keeps on retrying endlessly. How can I make it run only once or a few(n) times?

Also I use this script to stop the server :

```
c:\

cd c:\somefolder

forever stopall

cmd /k
```

It shows that no forever scripts are running when i run forever list but node.exe is active when I check the resource monitor. This causes the port to be blocked. ( It is a VM server and multiple users use it).

Answer (score 0):

What’s happen if you 1st check if services is running?

```
@echo off 

cd /d c:\somefolder

:check_again
(
%__APPDIR__%tasklist.exe /nh | %__APPDIR__%find.exe /I  "forever_service_name" >nul 
) && (
echo/ Services Forever is Running & Goto :next
) || (
forever start server.js
%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe /t 5
goto :check_again
)

:next
Rem :: Do some task, the services running...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't check that. Can you tell if pause or sleep maybe causing this issue?

Comment: @AbdulAhad you need edit “service name” add true name to work...

Comment: @AbdulAhad forever is a .exe file?

Comment: @AbdulAhad sleep/timeout does nothing have cause for this

Comment: the script is a batch file(.bat). Forever is a npm library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: @AbdulAhad yep, save as file.cmd or file.bat